# MySQL: Searching for a request using NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql

First of all, i want to apologize for my bad english.
I have a problem on mySQL and i didn't get the right idea to solve.

I have 3 Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE branch (name CHAR(30), city VARCHAR(30), assets NUMERIC(16,2), PRIMARY KEY (name));

CREATE TABLE account (accountNr CHAR(9), branch CHAR(30), balance NUMERIC(12,2), PRIMARY KEY (accountNr), FOREIGN KEY (branch) REFERENCES branch(name));

CREATE TABLE customer (customerId INT(5), accountNr CHAR(9), PRIMARY KEY (customerId, accountNr), FOREIGN KEY (accountNr) REFERENCES account(accountNr));
```

I should find a request to find the costumerId's of the customer who have an account in **all** branches where city = 'New York'. I must use the 'NOT EXISTS' condition.

So i know, i have two amounts:

A. the amount of branches where the customers have an account.

B. the amount of all branches in New York

Idea: Pick all customers where B is a subset of A

Comment: So you would like to supply "New York" and have all customers with an account in that city returned?  Also, please post the MySQL that you have already tried.

Comment: Yes, they cant have an account at more than one branch.

My first try:

    SELECT customerId
    FROM customer
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT name FROM branch WHERE city='New York')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this query:

> ```
> select distinct customerId
> from customer out_customer where 
> ( select count(account.accountNr) from account inner join branch on      account.branch = branch.name
> INNER join customer ON customer.accountNr = account.accountNr
> where city='New York' AND out_customer.customerId = customer.customerId ) = (select count(name) from branch where city='New York')
> ```